# How to iterate throgh a vector within vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector within a vector defined as:

```
std::vector<std::vector<myObj>> some_list(list_size);
```

some of the entries in some_list have elements and some don't those that have 3 elements have size 3 those with 4 have size 4 etc. for example:

```
some_list[0] {size=3}
some_list[1] {size=4}
```

but at some point there is an empty entry with 0 elements such as:

```
some_list[14] {size=0}
```

after which point every entry that follows has size 0 as well.

I am trying to resize my vector so it excludes such entries and is left with only the entries that have elements. But for some reason I can't make it work. Here's what I have:

```
int snum = 0;

      for (std::vector<std::vector<myObj>>::iterator a_it = a_list.begin(); 
          a_it != a_list.end(); a_it++) {
              while (a_it->size() != 0) {
                  snum++;
              }
      }

a_list.resize(snum);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure all the entries after the first empty one will also be empty, you can use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to get an iterator to the first empty element, then use [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase):

```
#include <algorithm>

bool is_empty(const std::vector<myObj>& v) { return v.empty(); }

v.erase(std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_empty), v.end() );
```

or, if you have C++11 support, you can use a lambda:

```
v.erase(std::find_if(v.begin(), 
                       v.end(), 
                       [](const std::vector<myObj>& v){ return v.empty(); }), 
        v.end() );
```

where I used `v` is `some_list`.

Oherwise, if empty entries are not all at the end, you can remove the entries with zero elements using the [erase remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) with a suitable function.

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_empty), v.end() );
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really informing.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
while (a_it->size() != 0) {
```

should probably read:

```
if (a_it->size() != 0) {
```

Comment: Note that you can also use `if (!a_it->empty()) {` which is more descriptive, I just wanted to avoid messing with that part to point out the real bug in the code. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should first *remove* the empty elements. You can do with with a ready-made algorithm:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

some_list.erase(std::remove_if(some_list.begin(), some_list.end(),
                               std::mem_fn(&std::vector<myObj>::empty),
                some_list.end());
```

*Then* you can resize: `some_list.resize(N)`. In fact, if you want the new elements to be empty anyway, you can skip the `erase` step and only do the `remove_if` part.